# Autocomplete textbox in C# for windows application

Tags: c#

when i run this code this error comes..

> object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
AutoCompleteStringCollection namesCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

string ConString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConString))
{
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT NAME FROM CUSTOMER", con);
    con.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    AutoCompleteStringCollection MyCollection = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        MyCollection.Add(reader.GetString(0));
    }
    txtcname.AutoCompleteCustomSource = MyCollection;
    con.Close();

}
```

Comment: On which line you get the error?

Comment: .ConnectionString here iam geting the error..

Comment: Then you likely have a problem with your config file, or your connection string isn't named ConString

Comment: @user3256868: your config file should have the connectionstring with name `ConString` check my answer for more info.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem :** i'm sure that you didn't declare the connection string in your config file under `<ConnectionStrings>` section.

OR

you might have declared it with some defferent `Key` name but not `ConString`.

**Solution:** you should declare the proper Connection String with Name `ConString` in your config file under `<ConnectionStrings>` section.

Make sure that your config file either `App.Config` or `web.config` has `ConnectionString` similar to following:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ConString" connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Intial Catalog=DatabaseName;UID=userID;Password=password;Integrated Security=True;" />
</connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your connection string in web.config something like

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConString" connectionString="server=localhost;database=myDb;uid=myUser;password=myPass;" />
</connectionStrings>
```